# JS - Undeclared identifier: 'var' in GLSL script

Tags: javascript, html, glsl, webgl

I'm a bit new to HTML and Javascript and within my html, I have the following code:

```
        <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
                precision mediump float;

                //varying vec3 fragmentColor;  //not needed?
                varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
                varying vec3 fragmentLight;
                varying vec3 fragmentView;

                uniform vec3 modelColor;
                uniform vec3 lightColor;

                void main() {
                        var m = normalize(fragmentNormal);
                        var l = normalize(fragmentLight);
                        var v = normalize(fragmentView);
                        var h = normalize(l + v);

                        var d = Math.max(l * m , 0);
                        var s = Math.pow(Math.max(h * m, 0), 10);

                        fragmentColor = modelColor * lightColor * d + lightColor * s;

                        gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor, 1.0);
                }
        </script>
```

However, it returns

```
Failed to compile shader: ERROR: 0:13: 'var' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:13: 'm' : syntax error
```

Am I not allowed to declare/define variables inside of script tags in HTML?

Comment: Even though it is a `script` element, it is not processed as one since you have specified a custom `type` value, it is instead processed by the `shader` compiler where the `var` is not a valid syntax thus the error.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code above is not JavaScript it's [GLSL](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shaders-and-glsl.html). It's the language used to write programs that run on your GPU. It doesn't have a keyword `var`. Instead to declare variables in GLSL you need to put a type in front of them

```
vec3 m = normalize(fragmentNormal);

vec3 l = normalize(fragmentLight);
vec3 v = normalize(fragmentView);
vec3 h = normalize(l + v);

vec3 d = max(l * m , 0.0);
vec3 s = pow(max(h * m, 0.0), vec3(10));
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do above but all your equations produce `vec3`.

Also GLSL 1.00 es is strict about types. You can't use vec3 with integers. You have to use floating point numbers. `0.0` instead of `0`.  The last line there is no function `pow` that takes a vec3 on the left and a single value on the right so `vec3(10)` takes the integer `10` and casts it to a `vec3`. It's the same as saying `vec3(10, 10, 10)`.

Also GLSL doesn't have a `Math.` library. It's built in functions are global.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I went through my console errors and cleaned it up accordingly.